# How to display a window half of its original size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm printing a WPF window in A4, so originally the window size is rather big. I would like to display it half the size of the original without modifying the printing output. Any ideas?

This is my method where I print

```
private void printItemList(string printerName)
    {
        //printButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        //cancelButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        printDlg.PrintQueue = new System.Printing.PrintQueue(new System.Printing.PrintServer(), printerName);
        System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);

        //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
        double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                       this.ActualHeight);

        //Transform the Visual to scale
        this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

        //get the size of the printer page
        Size sz = new Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight); //(8.5 * 96.0, 11.0 * 96.0);

        //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
        this.Measure(sz);
        this.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

        //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
        printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Print Page");
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
```

Comment: Please outline the methodology you are using to print it

Comment: can you elaborate more on your print window

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the content in a viewbox?

Comment: ViewBox does what I was thinking, I just have to make sure it is resized before printing executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBox does what I was thinking, I just have to make sure it is resized before printing executed. Thanks for the tip.